# API fails to return response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

I'm implementing a api made by gadventures.com in a ASP.NET MVC app project.

I have implemented below code to call the api

[image]

IsSuccessStatusCode returns false for the above code. It returns 401 unauthorized error. But I am able to get response in Postman.

[image]

Can you please help me to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header you are adding in postman is different to what you are doing in the code.

The code is setting `.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` with a scheme and parameter, which would look like this when the request is sent.

```
Authorization X-Application-Key test_21be144dea7e9fa41b5817fe56d2697a2cfc1b20
```

while postman is adding a generic header, which would look like this when sent

```
X-Application-Key test_21be144dea7e9fa41b5817fe56d2697a2cfc1b20
```

Update the code to do the same thing.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Application-Key","test_21be144dea7e9fa41b5817fe56d2697a2cfc1b20");
```